# Tailwind dosen't work on vue 4.3.1 with Sass

Tags: vue.js, sass, tailwind-css

I am trying to add tailwind to vue project, in order to do this I am following the next steps:

Version of vue

```
vue --version
@vue/cli 4.3.1
```

Create project

```
vue create tailwindproject
(node-sass, babel, router, eslint, with dedicated files)
```

Install tailwind

```
npm install tailwindcss
```

Create css file on:

```
touch ./src/styles/tailwind.scss
```

Copy the following content on `./src/assets/styles/tailwind.scss`

```
@tailwind base;

@tailwind components;

@tailwind utilities;
```

Add the following line into main.js

```
import './assets/styles/tailwind.scss'
```

Execute

```
npm run serve
```

And appears the following message

> Failed to resolve loader: sass-loader You may need to install it.

Install `sass-loader` with

```
npm install --save sass-loader
```

And appear the following error:

> ```
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Error: Cannot find module 'sass'
> ```

I solved this with:

```
npm install --save-dev node-sass
```

Run server again, but the view looks without tailwind css.

are there any way of install correctly tailwind with sass and vue4?

Thanks

Comment: I restarted my server

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the compiled css file through postcss. TailwindCSS is a postcss plugin, Sass cannot do anything with it. I think you should [check the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#using-tailwind-with-postcss) again.

Basically create a `postcss.config.js` file with this:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss'),
  ]
}
```

Then import your `tailwind.css` file in Vue.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use tailwind cli `npx tailwindcss init` to setup tailwind.